# Retrieve GAE Datastore's data types in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to retrieve data types of properties of entities stored in  Google App Engine Datastore using Java? I didn't find property.getType() or similar method in Java Datastore API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method provided.

but you can retrieve it by comparing the java Type of Property with the table given at this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types)

```
Map<String, Object> properties = entity.getProperties();
    String[] propertyNames = properties.keySet().toArray(
        new String[properties.size()]);

    for(final String propertyName : propertyNames) {
      // propertyNames string contains
      // "com.google.appengine.api.users.User" then its Google Accounts user
      // "java.lang.Integer" then its Integer
      // "int" then premetive integer
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I try out your code, but it doesn't help. I only get the property name (e.g. address), this string "propertyName" in my case doesn't contain the associated data type (e.g. string, java.lang.String or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Property Metadata Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Property_Queries_Non_Keys_Only_Property_Representation).

Be aware that, as stated in the documentation, the property representation returned by the queries would be AppEngine representation, and does not have one-to-one mapping with Java classes. But you would be able to get the general data type at least.

Comment: I also have found one possible solution where I inspect the canonical class name from property's entry set:

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
                          
              String dataType = entry.getValue().getClass().getCanonicalName();
}

Comment: @user1794211: If you think that approach better address your question, (and it seems to be, especially since that it does not seems to involve an extra datastore call), then feel free to submit a more detailed answer and accept it. You would help future devs that encounter the same problem. :)